# C++ nested iterators

Tags: c++, iterator, nested-loops, random-access

Is it OK to have a nested iterator like the following?

```
for (vector<type>::iterator i = list.begin(); i != list.end(); ++i) {
    for (vector<type>::iterator j = i; j != list.end(); ++j) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Note that `j` starts at `i`, and not `list.begin()`. Since the iterator is random access, can I guarantee that both `i` and `j` will have the same order? is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: You're not nesting iterators (which doesn't make sense in itself). You're nesting loops, and copying iterators. There's nothing strange here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is correct.

Both iterators will have the same order and incrementing `j` doesn't affect `i` as long as you don't make any operation that [*invalidates iterators*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6438087/13767) (for example erasing from or pushing to vector).

Comment: There isn't really any "the documentation" for C++, but see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks for the link! You are right, I simplified too much writing that sentence.

Answer (score 3):

This is absolutely fine as long as you don't do anything *inside* the loops that might invalidate iterators.

(As an aside, `list` is a questionable name for a `std::vector` in my opinion.)

Comment: +1 for mentioning the choice of the name of a standard container as the name of a variable. I've been seeing this very often lately (`array`, `list`, `map`, etc.).

Comment: the actual name is of course not list, just shortened it so that it would be easier to read in this forum.

Answer (score 3):

That's perfectly fine. Random access doesn't mean random order. It means that you can jump through the container by using additive operators (`+` and `-`) on your iterator. For example, with a random access iterator `it`, you can do `it + 10`. For an non-random access iterator, you would have to do `it++` 10 times to achieve the same effect. (the `std::advance` function will encapsulate this for you though)

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine.  Vector stores elements in order, and both iterators will obey this order.